# Converting PDF document containing graphs and tables to Word Document

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a PDF document to a Word file using Java. On Internet, I found a code snippet which converts PDF document to Word. but the alignments in the resulting Word document is clumsy. Images tables and graphs are not in sync. Everything is displaying as string paragraph/words.

The code, I have written is given below.

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();                         
String pdf = "D:\\xyz.pdf";            
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);          
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);                         
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {              
TextExtractionStrategy strategy = (TextExtractionStrategy) 
parser.processContent(i,new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());                
String text = strategy.getResultantText();                             
XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();                
XWPFRun run = p.createRun();                
run.setText(text);              
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
```

Please anyone help.....

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: That issue depends on the complexity of the pdf file. What kind of elements are in that pdf file?

Comment: PDF file has tables and graphs and normal content includes different font size and bold words.